# How to get information if strings in a column are left aligned and how to create new cells with this information in another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

In one sheet I have a Column which has left and right aligned strings. I need to filter all left aligned and create a new Cell/Row for each one.

I've started with

```
Sub test()
    Dim c As Variant
    For Each cell In Columns("C")
        If cell.HorizontalAlignment <> xlLeft Then
        Else: c = cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

This is just my basic idea and it sure does not work but maybe someone can help me how i can build what i need based on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim r1 As Long, r2 As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Start Row for output sheets
    r1 = 1: r2 = 1

    With oSht
        lastRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lastRow
            '~~> I am using Sheet2 and Sheet3. Change as applicable
            If .Range("C" & i).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft Then
                .Range("C" & i).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & r1)
                r1 = r1 + 1
            ElseIf .Range("C" & i).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight Then 'xlGeneral????
                .Range("C" & i).Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & r2)
                r2 = r2 + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Also note that `xlRight` may not be what you think it is. It maybe `xlGeneral` so you may want to check it. By default numbers are aligned to the right and text to the left in `xlGeneral`

Comment: i think so yes, but the "do what you want here" is also a problem. Now that I have my cells, how can i put them one after one into another sheet?

Comment: I have updated the post. You may want to refresh the page to see it

Comment: thanks for your help so far! I changed everything so that it should work. I do not get an error msg or something like that. But nothing happens. No new cells appear

Comment: The above code is tried and tested :) It worked for me.

Comment: maybe a mac issue?

Comment: Oh you are on a Mac? Excel 2011 or 2016?

Comment: 2016 :)

At home i use my windows PC but at Uni i only have my macbook. Makes things a bit complicated

Comment: One moment testing it on excel 2011

Comment: Yes it works on MAC as well. I think I know what the problem is. You copied the code as it is. In your case, the data is in Col C and not Col A. So you have to change that. I have updated the post. you may have to refresh the page to see it

Comment: thanks, some stuff is working now but i get weird formatting issues. I'll try to work that out now. You helped a lot. Much appreciated!

Comment: f you mean that the source formatting is being carried to other sheets then you have to change the line `.Range("C" & i).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & r1)` to `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & r1).Value = .Range("C" & i).Value` and similarly for `.Range("C" & i).Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & r2)`

Comment: thanks, got that fixed :) 
I've got another question that is based on my current results. I'll ask it here, if that is ok. If not please move the question or let me know.


So i made a mistake. I will have my data in sheet2 and sheet3 as you called it and will need to import it into sheet1. In another sheet, lets call it sheet4 i have a table where to next each left aligned word there is a right aligned word. Basically the right aligned words are a subcategory of the left aligned words. In sheet1 i need to have the right aligned words under the left aligned words accordingly.

Comment: It should be a different question :)

Comment: oh ok, ill open a new question then!

Comment: well i can only ask ever 90 minutes unfortunately, guess ill have to wait then :D